# How do people know that IP address belongs to VPN?

Tags: vpn

It seems that many servers know that I use VPN. They either block me completely or make me answer CAPTCHA etc.

I want to use VPN but seems that many hosts don't want their customers to use VPN. How do they know that I use VPN? And how could I use VPN without people knowing about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your VPN-provider has a static IP address or maybe an IP address range. Due to this, destination hosts will be able to tell if you are using a VPN or have an IP address from another range not belonging to a VPN provider.
To use VPN without people knowing you are doing so, you would have to get a VPN endpoint IP address not listed in any VPN IP lists.

Comment: Are these VPN IP lists easily available somewhere?

Comment: Try searching for "vpn blacklist" - although it seems that you have to pay for access to such lists.

Comment: Most of these lists are either paid or completely private to vendors only.

Answer (score 1):

Large, commercial web sites usually subscribe to a so-called "geo-location provider" such as, for example, [Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home). These services maintain large databases of IP ranges that identify the geographic location of the address and whether or not it is a proxy.

You can experiment with lesser known VPNs to try to get around this, but it may still get frustrating.

One possible solution is to make your own tunnel. Subscribe to an ISP that will give you a small amount of disk space and an account on a Linux machine. Install tunneling softare on the (virtual) machine they give you. Then use that machine as your proxy. The recorded IP address will be that of the virtual machine you have rented.

Answer (score 0):

Try vpngate.net it's a volunteer run vpn.

I disagree somewhat with what user1164xx said, having paid VPN doesn't mean you won't get blocked. It hasn't got anything to do with it (the money paid to the VPN).
And is there anything called a private/non-public 'VPN' by that the only user is yourself, if you didn't built one yourself and have it password locked with yourself. And maybe your company/organizations VPN which is not really private too, since the admins surely could see log if they do log.

I agree with rbialon. Basically I think if the VPN uses static / static ip ranges then it will surely have higher chance to get blocked. (just common sense)

Why not try out vpn before subscribing, most legit vpn that I know of provides free trials. That way you could know if it's blocked and also of its ip ranges that it uses.

There was a famous paid vpn that betrayed its customers and resulted in arrest of annonymous member. But I am not gonna proactively name names here (not really familiar of the rules here too) or even advertise for some of them paid ones here.

Answer (score -1):

The use of VPN is not prohibited and in most cases not penalized.
I believe your problem is in **WHAT** VPN are you using? Is it public VPN? God I hope not.

How do they know you are using VPN? They do not. All they can see is the VPN public address and that's how they decide whether you are allowed to communicate with them or not. If you are using a public VPN, how can you be sure that anyone else sharing the same VPN (and address) is not attacking servers and therefore banning the IP address? Vendors have different blacklists, but try to google some blacklists and check your public IP if it's not been blacklisted.

You need to provide more information for fuller response, like:

- are you using public VPN?
- for what purpose are you using VPN?
- are the servers blocking you when you're not on VPN?

Best regards.

M

Comment: I prefer to use VPN to avoid all kind of tracking. What do you mean by public VPN?

Comment: Mostly VPN that's free and anyone can use it.

Comment: I use paid VPNs.

Comment: Then I recommend you to contact VPN providers support and ask them to resolve the problem. Or you can always change your VPN provider.

Comment: Your assertions are not true 1) using a VPN can be against a site's policies (e.g. video streaming outside jurisdictions), and 2) VPN services tend to use a known block of IPs as rbialon states in his answer, so it can be known that one is using a VPN.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I assumed VPN as technology in general, not as a provider. No one's gonna trace out you are connected to your work VPN. Otherwise yes, VPN providers are stuck with certain addresses and may be on the blacklists, but the question didn't provide enough input. You can not determine VPN connection in general.